# Can we update tags on struct fields via reflection?

Tags: go, struct

I would like to know if we can update tag on a struct instance before unmarshaling data into it.

```golang
type Response struct {
    Name    string          `json:"name"`
    Payload json.RawMessage `json:"default"`
}

var data Response
<update tag on data.Payload to say `json:"id"`>
json.Unmarshal(server_response, &data)
```

The motivation is to load common keys in Response struct and delegate API specific response to API handler by passing the raw Payload.

The Payload fields, are complex structs, hence being parsed in their own handlers makes it cleaner.

Need to apply the tag, to let json.Unmarshal know which key from server_response to map to Payload.

The metadata fields (like Name) need some validations. So, if I pass the entire response to handler, each handler has to extract each field and return this metadata, which is well, not a very clean approach.

Decoding response to map[string]interface{} also leads to same issue. I want all the fields of metadata in one struct, populated automatically and handler to parse payload. Decoding to generic map, means copying keys.

Example:

```golang
type Response struct {
  Version int
  Name string
  Hash string
  Payload json.RawMessage
}
```

Would like the main function to load the server response in this object, to be able to do all kinds of validations and pass on Payload to handler to let it deal with it.

Using generic map means writing code like:
decodedData.Version = genericMap["version"] 
which does not scale to lots of keys.

Comment: I think it's impossible.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing ? If you know at the first place that you want the fied `id` in your json, why not set it to `id` ?

Comment: @edkeveked I am exploring a different approach. The server_response will have metadata fields and one payload field which I would like to just pass on to the API response handler to unmarshal it. But to load the object in data, I need to apply the tag.

Comment: Why do you need to apply the tag to load the data ? That does not seem clear to me

Comment: @edkeveked Updated the description. Basically, either the field name should match the key or the json tag should. So, if I have a Payload with tag as `json:"stats"` and the response json has a field "stats", the whole stats field will be loaded into Payload as a raw json.

Comment: Struct tags are a feature of the type, and types are immutable at runtime. You could create a new type using reflection but it's going to be even harder to work with than a `map`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, why don't you simply pass the entire response to the handler? The handler will then know if it needs to read from the `stats` or the `id` or whatever field... https://play.golang.org/p/pQXa3Gm_WS0 shows roughly the idea.

An alternative would be to decode your response into a `map[string]interface{}` and to use https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure afterwards to decode parts of the response into structs.

Comment: Updated description to state why I don't want to use generic map.

Comment: I understand your point about generic maps, and that's precisely where the `mapstructure` package comes into play: it allows you to "unmarshal" a `map[string]interface{}` into a struct, removing the need to write code like `decodedData.Version = genericMap["version"]`.